# Remap doesn't work by AutoHotKey except for an application

Tags: autohotkey

I want to remap `right ctrl+a` to `Home` by using `Autohotkey` except an application named `xyzzy`.

This is the code I wrote.

```
if not WinActive("ahk_exe xyzzy.exe")
  >^a::Home
```

The remap works with other application like Notepad, but also remaps when using `xyzzy.exe`.

`ahk_exe` name is checked by `AU3_Spy.exe` as the image below.

[image]

How can I exclude specific application from key remapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
#IfWinNotActive ahk_exe xyzzy.exe

  >^a:: Send {Home}

#If
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm

or

```
>^a::
    If !WinActive("ahk_exe xyzzy.exe") ; "!" means "NOT" in this case
    Send {Home}
return
```

Comment: Thanks! so I need to use `if directive` instead of `if statement` when making hotkeys.

Comment: Not necessarily, the #if directive is useful when a particular program ignores a key (- combination) or performs some action you find undesirable. See the edited answer.